# Not able to pass Array into another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

`response` is an `array` returned by my `API`. I am passing this `variable` to another component to create table in UI.

```
const [response, setResponse]= useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (
      async () => {
        await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates').
        then(response=>{
            setResponse(response.data);
            setFlag(true);
        })   
     }
    )()
  }, []);
```

I am using this `response` to another `component` to create table.

```
const ResultTable = (response: any[]) => {
-----------code------
----------code------
}
```

I am calling component like below.

```
                    <tbody> 
                      <ResultTable response={response}/>  //this line giving error
                    </tbody>
```

[image]

what mistake I am doing?

if I do like below

```
({response}: any[])
```

it does not recognize response variable. my file is `.tsx`
[image]

Comment: You forgot to destructure your props in `ResultTable`

Comment: can you guide me for the same please.

Comment: `const ResultTable = ({ response }: { response: any[] }) => {...};`

Comment: Man you are really a genius. this resolved the issue. can you copy paste this line in answer so that I can accept. it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Your **ResultTable** component should looks something like this,

```
const ResultTable = ({ response }) => {
-----------code------
----------code------
}
```

Comment: thank you Arun. Actually ,After I did the same, it is not recognizing the response variable inside the resulttable component. I did spell check and all

Comment: Updated the answer, can you try now!!!

Comment: anything insdie curly bracket is not getting recognized...same as previous one

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the destructuring at `ResultTable` as:

```
const ResultTable = ({response}: any[]) => {
-----------code------
----------code------
}
```

Also, update the state initialization as

```
const [response, setResponse]= useState<any[]>([]);
```

Comment: Thanks Neeraj. I have attached the error in question. it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned this too but empty array is automatically infered to the type "never". I believe if you change your useState hook to this:

```
 useState([] as any);
```

it will work.

And also change this one to `const ResultTable = ({ response })`

Comment: Thank you Kevin..actually its not working. same error